# How do I set a Windows 7 Security Policy option to "not defined"?

Tags: windows-7, security-policy

I have two identical machines running Windows 7, and I'm trying to replicate the security policy settings of one on the other (these are the settings under `secpol.msc`).

One machine has a setting `Local Policies > Security Options > Network security: LAN Manager authentication level` setting of `Not Defined`. The other has one of the options selected.

How do I reset that option to "Not Defined"? It doesn't appear in the list of options when I open its properties and there's no visible action to clear it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the regkey entry (DWORD) `LmCompatibilityLevel` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\Lsa` and reboot.

Comment: This also works in Windows 10. (10.0.15063)